# How to return sentence that contains specific words in PHP

Tags: php

As in title i am wondering how i can easly return sentences only if they contains specific word inside?

Lets say i have an array:

```js
$strings = array("Hello World", "Hello Earth", "Hi World");
$match = "Hello";
foreach ($strings as $string) {
  echo $string;
  //And here i want to return only strings with "Hello",
  //In this case it should only return:
  //Hello World,
  //Hello Earth
}
```

Anyone could help? :)

Comment: Welcome. Please show what you've tried. You could for instance [`explode`](http://www.php.net/explode) your string into words then use [`in_array`](http://www.php.net/in_array), or use [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/preg_match) with word boundaries.

Comment: Take a look at `array_filter()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use strpos() to check whether string contains a selected word.

```
$strings = array("Hello World", "Hello Earth", "Hi World");
$match = "Hello";
foreach ($strings as $string) {
  if (strpos($string, $match) !== false) {
      echo $string;
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that this will not match words per se. Could be part of words.